# Wordpress page.php source code

Tags: wordpress

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="content-wrap ninecol clearfix">
        <div class="content">
           <h1 class="title">Om oss</h1>
           <hr>
           <div class="entry-content">
           <h4>Vilka är Unified Sweden?</h4>
           <p>Unified Sweden är en webbyrå som ständigt strävar </p>
        </div>
    <div>
 </div>
```

if I would want to make this as a template so that I can use it for other pages is the code below right?

```
<div class="content-wrap ninecol clearfix">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="content">
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                 <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

                 <?php the_content(); ?>

            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

Comment: please fix your closing tags :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should have a look at the [Wordpress Template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) and [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates).

You should create a file called `page-<something-you-want>.php`. Open the file and add a template name to it and add your content.

For example:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: A Static Page
 */
get_header(); ?>

<whatever content you want to add>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Then go to `Add new Page`, and in the `Page Attribute` box, you'll see a dropdown called `Template`. You select the template called  `A Static Page` (or otherwise defined above) and publish the page. That's all.

**To get the content**

To get the content in Wordpress, you need to [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();       
  the_content(); // displays whatever you wrote in the wordpress editor
  endwhile; endif; //ends the loop
 ?>
```

Getting back to your case:

```
 <div class="sevencol">
   <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
       <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
         <div>
           <?php the_content(); ?>
         </div>
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm aware of that, the thing is I want to be able to apply the template to other pages, my question was maybe nout specific enough but there should be a code that goes between header.php and footer.php that displays static content right? like get_the_content or something like that. I mean lets say I have 2 pages that uses div class"half" and one page that ises div class"full", it means I need two templates. I dont know what code that goes inside each div to show the content.. I'm not very good at explaining sorry I'm new to worpress

Comment: @rrkesh thank you so much, I knew there was something funny with the one I have

Comment: I updated my question, could you please have a look? thank you anyway

Comment: You should not just delete the original question and write a whole new question instead. Either append your new question to the end or create a new question. To answer your new question: NO. Your HTML structure is not the same.